# How to use Pandas to get date_range from some timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to split a year in enumerated 20-minute chunks and then find the sequece number of corresponding time range chunk for randomly distributed timestamps in a year for further processing.
I tried to use pandas for this, but I can't find a way to index timestamp in date_range:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date_start = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
    date_end = date_start + timedelta(days=365)
    index = pd.date_range(start=date_start, end=date_end, freq='20min')
    data = range(len(index))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['A'])
    print(df)

    event_ts = pd.to_datetime('2018-10-14 02:17:43')
    # How to find the corresponding df['A'] for event_ts?
    # print(df.loc[event_ts])
```

Output:

```
                         A
2018-01-01 00:00:00      0
2018-01-01 00:20:00      1
2018-01-01 00:40:00      2
2018-01-01 01:00:00      3
2018-01-01 01:20:00      4
...                    ...
2018-12-31 22:40:00  26276
2018-12-31 23:00:00  26277
2018-12-31 23:20:00  26278
2018-12-31 23:40:00  26279
2019-01-01 00:00:00  26280

[26281 rows x 1 columns]
```

What is the best practice to do it in python? I imagine how to find the range "by hand" converting date_range to integers and comparing it, but may be there are some elegant pandas/python-style ways to do it?

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)? It's not quite clear to me what should be your original `df`.

Comment: @rpanai I use df here only for storing indexes of time-range chunks. In my task I want to make list of objects of some class that make processing. I need to make a relation: event timestamp -> certain instance of object in list. I am not sure if DF can store class objects. Processing of event needs some additional workaround, like selecting additional data from mysql and so on. Classes are iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I've worked with a small interval, one week:

```
date_end = date_start + timedelta(days=7)
```

Then I've followed your steps, and got a portion of your dataframe.

My event_ts is this:

```
event_ts = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-04 02:17:43')
```

And I've chosen to reset the index, and have a dataframe easy to manipulate:

```
 df = df.reset_index()
```

With this code I found the last value where event_ts belongs:

```
 for i in df['index']:
      if i <= event_ts:
          run.append(i)

 print(max(run))
 #2018-01-04 02:00:00
 or:
 top = max(run)
```

Finally:

```
 df.loc[df['index'] == top].index[0]
 222
```

event_ts belongs to index df[222]